# Winamp doesn't remember my playlist between reboots since I use Win 8.1

Tags: windows, winamp

After recently switched from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1, Winamp's playlist gets emptied after every reboot. I've never seen such behaviour and have no idea why it does that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Winamp is not designed for Win8. You can switch to another player or reinstall it.

Comment: could you back that up? What exactly is *that* different?

Comment: According to http://www.filehorse.com/download-winamp/ it is